# Vue - How to I extract template to a mixin?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a mixin like:

`MixinElTable.vue`

```
export default {
  components: { Pagination },
  data: () => ({
    listData: [],
    listLoading: true,
    listQuery: {
      page: 1,
      limit: 10
    },
    ...
  }),
  computed: {
    filteredData() {
      return this.listData.filter(data => {
        return this.searchData === '' ||
          data[this.searchKey].toLowerCase().includes(this.searchData.toLowerCase())
      })
    }
    ...
  }
...
}
```

Then, I use it in several views:

`ProjectList.vue`

```
export default {
  name: 'ProjectList',
  mixins: [MixinElTable],
  ...
```

`IssueList.vue`

```
export default {
  name: 'IssueList',
  mixins: [MixinElTable],
  ...
```

In the `<script>` block I can use everything from the mixin to avoid writing duplicated code. But, in the `<template>` block I need to copy and paste code for each view such as:

```
    <el-table v-loading="listLoading" :data="pagedData" :element-loading-text="$t('Loading')" border fit
              highlight-current-row height="100%" :cell-style="{height: rowHeight + 'px'}">
    ...(Something specific to each view like ProjectList or IssueList etc.)
    </el-table>
    <pagination
      :total="filteredData.length"
      :page="listQuery.page"
      :limit="listQuery.limit"
      :page-sizes="[listQuery.limit]"
      :layout="'total, prev, pager, next'"
      @pagination="onPagination"
    />
```

Since data like `listQuery` or `filteredData()` are stored in the view component, I can only use mixins rather than components. But Without using components, I don't know to avoid duplicated template code.

How can I pack the template code similar to a components like `<el-table-paged>`? By the way I'm using node.js version vue, if it matters.

Comment: Ahh naming collition = this is why `mixins` suck. Change your properties names in the `mixin` from `filteredData` to let say `mixin_pagination_filteredData` and there will not be naming collition anymore. Then you can create "standard" Component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mixins doesn't come with templates. Imagine you attached two mixins with templates to a component. How would the template of the mixins be merged?

I think this situation rater calls for using a component with a `<slot />`. You can still do what you want, just passing in the properties to the wrapper component. If you have any properties you need to pass on to the slotted component, you can pass variables to the slotted scope.
So instead of your mixin you would have the following wrapper component:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <el-table v-bind="$attrs">
      <slot v-bind:filteredData="filteredData" />
    </el-table>
    <pagination ... />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'WrapperElTable',
  props: { ... your required properties ... },
  computed: {
    filteredData() { return stuff; }
  },
  ...
};
</script>
```

And in your two separate components you would use this component like this:

```html
<template>
  <WrapperElTable :raw-data="rawData" :list-query="listQuery">
    <template v-slot:default="{ filteredData }">
      ...do stuff with filteredData, specific to ProjectList
    </template>
  </WrapperElTable>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ProjectList',
  components: {WrapperElTable},
  ...
};
</script>
```

Any `rawData`, `listQuery`, etc. can simply be passed as props to your base component.